# How to get source of image in WS app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I was wondering how to get source of image 
in Windows Store app with C#.
 Here is how to set the source
but I don't know how to get it.

```
var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///img/image.png");
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);
img.Name = "icon" + nbfood.Text;

img.Source = bitmap;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get source of image like how you set it:

```
ImageSource source = img.Source;
BitmapImage bitmapImage = source as BitmapImage;
```